# TensorFlow Estimator: how to do prediction when using parameter server?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, tensorflow-estimator

TensorFlow Estimator is easy to use for distributed training with parameter server strategy. But I cannot do prediction with the parameter server strategy. I cannot find any resource to introduce the part.

prediction sample code:

```
    run_config = tf.estimator.RunConfig()
    model = tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=self.model_fn,
        model_dir=self._config.model_path,
        config=run_config,
        params=self.params())
    results = model.predict(
        input_fn=lambda: test_data.build(
            batch_size=self._config.eval_batch_size,
            num_epochs=1))
```

TF_CONFIG:

```
{'task': {'index': '0', 'type': 'ps'}, 'cluster': {'chief': ['127.0.0.1:2320'], 'ps': ['127.0.0.1:2220', '127.0.0.1:2221']}}
{'task': {'index': '1', 'type': 'ps'}, 'cluster': {'chief': ['127.0.0.1:2320'], 'ps': ['127.0.0.1:2220', '127.0.0.1:2221']}}
{'task': {'index': '0', 'type': 'chief'}, 'cluster': {'chief': ['127.0.0.1:2320'], 'ps': ['127.0.0.1:2220', '127.0.0.1:2221']}}
```

Result: Both PS and Woker did prediction.

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In [Estimator predict](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py#L623), every ps and worker use `MonitoredSession` to start a node which restores from an existing checkpoint. In order to do a distributed prediction, you can refer to [Estimator training](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py).

- **[start ps](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/training.py#L716)**
- **[run_worker](https://github.com/tensorflow/estimator/blob/master/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py#L1357)** Create `MonitoredTrainingSession` instead of a `MonitoredSession`

  - Remember to start worker server.
- `estimator.predict` receives a `path` for checkpoint, `MonitoredTrainingSession` receives a `directory` for checkpoint.

You can successfully start all servers and a distributed prediction. But there will be warnings such as that the global step is not increasing.

[Detailed code on Github](https://github.com/chunyang-wen/estimator-tutorial/tree/master/dist-predict)